# AWS EC2 and storage type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm studying Amazon AWS EC2. I read a lot about *Instance stores* and EBS. But what about System space. Could I use system space as initial storage? What problem should I experience in this way?

As far as I can image: bytes on the system storage is more expensive than EBS, and more more expensive than Instance store (ephemeral). Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The key point you are missing when talking about system storage is general Amazon EC2 instances are not physical machines, but rather virtual machines managed using Hypervisor or similar virtualization platform.

Every new instance is a brand new virtualized image. Instance store is the ability to allocate storage on the disk physically attached to the server using the virtualization platform, and it needs to be ephemeral and size limited based on the instance type.

EBS is like a network storage drive, but AWS makes it really fast to access within its high speed data centers.

System storage is nothing but how OS manages the data on the selected storage type: Instance Store or EBS.